Android Audio recorder
I am looking for app to record audio, that actually supports Android.  My phone did not come with one installed.
I previously found two recording apps, including one by Dolby.  They store the recordings inside the app, and the app I used didn't support Google backups.  It only allowed exporting files one at a time, and I don't want to export each file at recording time.  This means there is no practical way to change phones.
I am willing to use an app without automatic backups, if necessary.  However, I do buy a new phone sometimes.  I hear that's not unusual :-).  I want my recording app to support that.
Sync to Google Drive would be fine.  However I often don't have internet, so the app can't rely on it when recording.
Of course I would prefer the app just worked, so it didn't add anything to the list of tasks when buying a new phone.  But if you have instructions for bulk backup/restore/transfer, that would be a 100% improvement on what I currently have.
Maybe there is something on the FDroid store?  (I hear Google Play Store makes it hard for app developers to use the filesystem.  At the same time as making it easy to not bother supporting backups, which Apple are more strict on.)
I am also cheap, but hey.  If there is an app that I won't hate, maybe I should support it.  Something that supports making multiple recordings, buying a new phone, and doesn't have ads or privacy violations etc.
If it matters, this is for relatively short clips of singing/music.  I am not looking for automatic transcription, or audio manipulation.  The ability to cut bits off the start/end of the recording is probably a good idea, but I don't really mind either way.

Fossify Voice Recorder, from Google Play store or FDroid.
This app allows manual backups, but not restores.
It is possible to backup because all recordings are saved as files in /Music/Recordings (or another folder you choose).  You can copy these files as usual, and you can open and play the copies using the file browser app, or VLC app, etc.
It is not possible to restore manually, because this app only has permission to play a file if it is the same file that the app recorded.  When manually restoring files, I suggest the least confusing approach is to put the files into a separate folder e.g. /Music/Old recordings.
Hopefully the recorded files are included in automatic copying when setting up a new phone, assuming you enable copying "Music".  I have not tested this.  Perhaps it even copies enough metadata that Fossify Voice Recorder can open the recordings on the new phone, but I would not rely on that :-).
The app I previously used was Audio Recorder (also open source and available on FDroid).  You might argue this app is no worse.  The recordings can be copied using USB file access (but not the phone's own file browser), from the folder /Android/data/com.dimowner.audiorecorder/files/Music/records/.  However, the documentation for this app is at best confusing, and does not explain this or any other practical method of backing up.  I prefer an app that provides at least some support to the user.  Also, I think the Fossify approach is better because then you have the permissions to back up the folder with SyncThing or equivalent.  Neither app provides automated backups itself.
